# Realistic expectations of a burner computer with 8 GB of memory

Tags: laptop

I'm about to buy a second hand Thinkpad x201i in order to learn how to use Linux and programming as a burner computer.

While I did watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=85gE5pQw3S0) and plan to order new batteries and RAM, I would like to get some feedback on whether this is a half-decent burner machine for my purposes. Also, what are realistic expectations with this machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get one for around $50, go for it. For programming and web browsing, it will work great.

Go download [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/download.html) and install it on a USB. It will let you load multiple ISOs and try out different distros.